# R ssh lib: how to pass parameters to enable ssh-rsa certificate?

Tags: r, ssh, libssh

I am using ssh library (install.packages("ssh")) for R on Mac to connect to a server for file transfer (sftp).
My server supports only ssh-rsa certificates.

First problem I got was key exchange error:

`kex error : no match for method server host key algo: server [ssh-rsa], client [ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256]`

I successfully circumvented this by adding certain parameters to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:
`Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,ssh-rsa MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,ssh-rsa KexAlgorithms ssh-rsa HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa`

connection string I use:
`ssh::ssh_connect("username@ip:port", keyfile ="Key/key", verbose = "1")`

Now I'am facing next error issue:

`ssh_userauth_publickey: The key algorithm 'ssh-rsa' is not allowed to be used by PUBLICKEY_ACCEPTED_TYPES configuration option`

Brief search shows that the problem is in underlying libssh library default parameter that does not allow ssh-rsa. But I don't see any possibility to set this parameter by using any function from R ssh:: library.

Are there any other ways how I can explicitly add ssh-rsa to PUBLICKEY_ACCEPTED_TYPES parameter of libssh from R or zsh?